# how to set html tag dir attribute from rtl to ltr and vice versa programmatically in c sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, multilingual

I'm trying to build a multilingual web site on asp.net and i need to set html tag dir attribute from rtl to ltr and vice versa programmatically in c sharp.
For now i have 3 languages english, hebrew and russian and i need to switch between them.
I need to change direction of a site every time i change from ltr to rtl language and from rtl to ltr language 
here the example of my masterpage
please help me

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs"     Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="CSS/Site-RTL.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="html" runat="server">
<form id="theForm" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSetEnglish" runat="server" Text="English" CommandArgument="en-GB"
        OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSetHebrew" runat="server" Text="Hebrew" CommandArgument="he-IL"
        OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSetRussian" runat="server" Text="Russian" CommandArgument="ru-RU"
        OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="smdsMaster" runat="server" OnDataBinding="Page_Load" />
    <asp:Menu ID="MenuMaster" runat="server" CssClass="menu" DataSourceID="smdsMaster"
        Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" StaticSubMenuIndent="16px" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1">
        <DataBindings>
            <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" NavigateUrlField="Url" />
        </DataBindings>
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

here a code behind a master page

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Localization.Classes;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}

protected void RequestLanguageChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton senderLink = sender as LinkButton;

    //store requested language as new culture in the session
    if (senderLink.CommandArgument == "he-IL")
    {
        // some code
    }
    else
    {
        // some code
    }
    Session[Global.SESSION_KEY_CULTURE] = senderLink.CommandArgument;

    //reload last requested page with new culture
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code behind:

```
this.html.Attributes.Add("dir", "ltr");
```

---

An alternative, if this is not working is to place the attribute directly on the tag and use a property to populate it:

```
<body dir="<%:Dir%>">

public string Dir { get; set; }

// Set Dir in the on click event

protected void RequestLanguageChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton senderLink = sender as LinkButton;

    //store requested language as new culture in the session
    if (senderLink.CommandArgument == "he-IL")
    {
        Dir = "rtl";
    }
    else
    {
        Dir = "ltr";
    }

    Session[Global.SESSION_KEY_CULTURE] = senderLink.CommandArgument;

    //reload last requested page with new culture
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);

}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work for me. I'l post a code behind.

Comment: @zZD1M0NZz - What gets rendered when you view source in the browser? Are you getting any errors? Exceptions?

Comment: No there is no errors or exceptions and there is no addition of rtl attribute to body tag

Comment: @zZD1M0NZz - Given another option.

Comment: sorry but, i didn't understand how to set dir in the on click event

Comment: @zZD1M0NZz - What's to understand. I have posted the code for the click event. You need to add a `Dir` property as I also posted.

Comment: Sorry but i'm new at this. Can you please spell it out for me and show me full code example of how it should be done.

Comment: @zZD1M0NZz - Apart from what I already posted, I don't really know what more I can say.

Comment: I have made a changes on my code example. Please tell me if that what you had in mind

Comment: @zZD1M0NZz - Apart from you now completely changing the question and making my answer invalid, yes, that's what I meant (though you should drop the `runat="server"` from the `<body>` element.

Comment: thank you for your patience. that solution doesn't worked for me.   ps. i changed the code example back so your answer is valid sorry for that

Comment: this is what i see in page source `<body dir=""  onclick="RequestLanguageChange_Click">
`

Comment: @zZD1M0NZz - OK. Can you set `Dir` in the `page_load` instead of the button click?